# PHP 7.3 SameSite=None for cross-site cookies in HTTPS

Tags: php, cookies, cross-site

I'm embedding https://website2.com into https://website1.com via an iframe.

It was working well until recently when Chrome changed its security policy requiring cookie SameSite set to None.
My https app has 2 cookies PHPSESSID and HASH_PHPSESSID.
I'm using PHP 7.3 and Jelix.

To set SameSite to None I now have:
`session_set_cookie_params(['samesite' => 'None', 'secure' => true]);
session_start();`.

As a result, PHPSESSID is correctly defined (Secure=True | SameSite = None).
However, I can't get HASH_PHPSESSID to be set (Secure=True | SameSite = )!

Any idea how to handle this in https?

Comment: So who/where/what is setting this `HASH_PHPSESSID` cookie then? That is probably done explicitly somewhere in the code, so … go figure out where?

Comment: I'm using Jelix librairies. I can't find where this is done in Jelix libs, no trace of a HASH_ cookie. This occurs when securing the app with https.